# system2("bash", "ls") -> cannot execute binary file

Tags: r, bash, system2

Anyone got an idea why

```
system2("bash", "ls")
```

would result in (both in R-Gui and RStudio Console)

```
/usr/bin/ls: /usr/bin/ls: cannot execute binary file
```

while other shells work w/o issues (see example below) and the "bash" in the RStudio Terminal also works w/o problems. AND if there is a remedy for that?

Working `system2` example:

```
system2("powershell", "dir")
```

Running R-3.6.3 on Windows 10 here ... with "Git bash" executing as "bash".

PS: just in case someone wonders - I also tried the full path ie `/usr/bin/ls` -> same result

Comment: `ls` is the plain vanilla "list content of current directory" bash command;        
just as "dir" is for powershell

Comment: Okay, but `bash ls` runs `ls` as a shell script, you need to do `bash -c ls`.

Comment: @oguzismail `args = "-c ls"` also works ...

Comment: @oguzismail - I was also always under the impression that `system2` would do exactly that `-c` part under the hood - as it does with `powershell` and `dir` (as its `args`) BUT never mind. 
Really fascinated by the downvotes especially since `system2` jumps all over the place depending on what combination of R, RStudio, PATH and Locale you are running. I thought that to be quite interesting to keep as a note to self - so glad to have that in here as my reminder.

Comment: I don't know R at all, I saw this question because you tagged it bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok - this does the trick

```
system2("bash", input = "ls")
```

so instead of `args = ...`  as with the `powershell` command one needs (or more interestingly sometimes 'can') use the `input = ...` parameter with `bash`

OR as mentioned in the comments by @oguzismail this will also work

```
system2("bash", "-c ls")
```

as well as pointed out by @Christoph

```
system2("ls")
```

also works sometimes (ie in some RStudio[?] setups it will not return results in some it will).

But I have come to notice that different combinations of R-versions with different RStudio versions [or more probably Locales] will not always behave consistently of course also depending on the availability of bash commands like `ls` (more generally /usr/bin) being on the PATH or not.

So choose what suits u best!

Comment: Why not just `system2("ls")`?

Comment: @Christoph - never expected that to work as well under WINDOWS, BUT after checking it seems to do the trick as well in SOME configurations BUT NOT ALL! Guess depends on PATH variable as well as some combinations of R and RStudio sometimes accepting parameters and sometimes rejecting them (eg because of inserting `\r` etc). It all looks a bit shaky underneath the ground ...